# How did the refrigerator light question get so many views?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[What do you do if you forgot to turn off the refrigerator light before Shabbat?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11025/what-do-you-do-if-you-forgot-to-turn-off-the-refrigerator-light-before-shabbat)

880 in less than a day? I am very curious.

Comment: Not in less than a day, but, yes, it's a lot.

Comment: Isn't the point of SE, that people ask questions on google and get the SE site as an answer?

Comment: @avi, sure, but this sort of traffic on a question right after it's asked is anomalous in the context of this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My first guess would be that someone with a lot of followers linked to it on Facebook or Twitter.

I've found [one mention](https://twitter.com/#!/andreskrey/status/131119578200817664) on Twitter, but it's not from someone with a lot of followers.

UPDATE: [Found it.](http://www.reddit.com/r/atheism/comments/lvqkz/how_these_people_get_by_each_week_is_beyond_me/) Note the number of subscribers to that particular subreddit. Anything that gets any traction at all there will be clicked on by many.

Comment: Judios creen en el infierno?http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4467/do-we-believe-in-heaven-and-hell

Answer (score 4):

I am going to telll you the truth .... When I found this question, I did something very special, which usually I do not do: I mailed it to my friends as 'the joke of the day' ... and they loved it, and forwarded it to their friends, etc ...